# installation HDBC-SQlite3 Haskell

Tags: sqlite, haskell

Im facing the problem during installation :

```
>>setup configure

Configuring HDBC-sqlite3-2.3.0.0...
setup: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: sqlite3
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

what should I do ?

thanks for any help

Comment: `This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK,

I downloaded sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.h from source zip.

then I inserted sqlite3.dll in system32 dir and in setup configure i used

--extra-lib-dirs=... --extra-include-dirs=...  parameters with correct paths to header and dll.

Comment: This worked very easily. HDBC should come with some default sqlite3 libraries for easy install.

Comment: This document proved to be very helpful. http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/how-to-install-hdbc-sqlite3-on-windows/

Comment: Which can now be found here: https://massaioli.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/how-to-install-hdbc-sqlite3-on-windows/

Answer (score 9):

You need to install the C library implementation and headers of SQLite.

On Ubuntu and other Debian-based Linux distros, it's simply

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Other Linux distros will have similarly named packages.

On Windows, you'll have to do some more work.

On OS X, I have no idea.